# Passing **kwargs received in a wrapper-function definition, to arguments of an enclosed (i.e. wrapped) function call

Tags: python, function, keyword-argument

Oh dear, I hope I got the title right. :)

How can one pass the **kwargs supplied to a *wrapper-function* *definition*, to another (enclosed) function *call* that it wraps. For example:

```
def wrapped_func(**kwargs):
   # Do some preparation stuff here.
   func('/path/to/file.csv', comma_separated_key=value_injected_here)
   # Do some other stuff.
```

So for example, this call:

```
wrapped_func(error_bad_lines=True, sep=':', skip_footer=0, ...)
```

Should result in this:

```
func('/path/to/file.csv', error_bad_lines=True, sep=':', skip_footer=0, ...)
```

I've tinkered with a variety of approaches over the past couple of hours, but each exposed *type-preservation* vulnerabilities (for the values). I've not used this particular wrapper pattern before, and was wondering if the community could give some help. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Care to explain what you mean about *type-preservation* vulnerabilities (in italics, no less)? What exactly changes? The code you show will, of course, not produce the result you say you expect, what is the *actual* code you are using?

Comment: Does func() also take **kwargs?

Comment: Hi Natecat. Great question, unfortunately it doesn't. The function is actually 'pandas.read_csv()' (already implemented).

Comment: What's wrong with `func('/path/to/file.csv', **kwargs)`?

Comment: Hi  user2357112. Thanks for the question. Functions calls (as opposed to Function definitions) don't accept **kwargs. One can use 'kwargs', but that is a dict() at that point, not the comma-separated k=v pairs expected.

Comment: @prismalytics.io actually they do

Comment: ** is the syntax for expanding dicts

Comment: Hi Peter Gibson and Natecat. I tried it in the call but couldn't get that to work. I'll double-check what I did (b/c now you guys have me wondering). Be right back. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`**kwargs` is a dict, meaning you can use the double splat (`**`) to [unpack it as a list of keyword arguments](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists). So your wrapper function could be like this:

```
def wrapped_func(**kwargs):
   # Do some preparation stuff here.
   func('/path/to/file.csv', **kwargs)
   # Do some other stuff.
```

Comment: I upvoted this (and all of the helpful comments from you and others above, too) and checked it as the solution. Oh dear,... the issue was a total red-herring: It was a pandas exception, not the unpacking of **kwargs exception (which I had tried an hour ago -- but again, a red-herring pandas-specific error). Sometimes you need another set of eyes. Thank you all! :)

Answer (score 2):

An easy way to define a very custom wrapper is to define your own class:

```
class AdditionWrapper:
    def __init__(self, func):
        self.func = func
    def __call__(self, **kwargs):
        return self.func('/path/to/file.csv', **kwargs)
```

You could also make the path customizable:

```
class AdditionWrapper:
    _path = '/path/to/file.csv'
    def __init__(self, func):
        self.func = func
    def __call__(self, **kwargs):
        return self.func(self._path, **kwargs)
    def set_path(self, path):
        self._path = path
```

Use:

```
@AdditionWrapper
def myfunc(...):
    ...

myfunc.set_path(mypath)
```

Comment: Thank you zondo. This (the solution you posted) is more like the pattern that I generally use. It wasn't applicable in this case (mostly because I'm already using a Python metaclass (metaclass=abc.ABCMeta), in my code and didn't want one more level of indirection. =:). I upvoted you solution for it's alternative approach (one that I generally use).

Answer (score 2):

Just use the same syntax when you call a function to expand the kwargs dict as keyword arguments:

```
func('/path/to/file.csv', **kwargs)
```

You can also pass in positional arguments in the same way

```
func('/path/to/file.csv', *args, **kwargs)
```

Here's a link to the Python docs on the subject: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists

Comment: Thank you Peter. Yeah you, Natecat (and others) were/are correct. This was the first thing I tried as it made total sense to do that. But the particular pandas exception threw me for a loop (believing that the expansion wasn't happening correctly, when in reality it was expanding correctly but pandas choking on the 'sep=':' parameter I passed to it (again via **kwargs, which did expand). Oh brother. LOL You answer upvoted, too.

Answer (score 2):

Why not simply merge the kwargs:

```
def func(*args, **kwargs):
    print args
    print kwargs


def wrapped_func(**kwargs):
    # Do some preparation stuff here.
    func('/path/to/file.csv', **dict(comma_separated_key='value_injected_here', **kwargs))
    # Do some other stuff.


wrapped_func(error_bad_lines=True, sep=':', skip_footer=0)

# Outputs:
('/path/to/file.csv',)
{'skip_footer': 0, 'error_bad_lines': True, 'comma_separated_key': 'value_injected_here', 'sep': ':'}
```

Comment: User has stated that func() isn't written by them

Comment: Sure, i only wrote it to print what would arrive to the function. As long as all arguments match the ones defined by `pandas.read_csv` they will be set correctly.

Comment: If he's wrapping the call to `pandas.read_csv` with some default values, then it's reasonable to be able to have the ability to merge and overwrite.

Comment: Thank you guys (and girls in case user1434070). All comments valid and upvoted. Thank you for the suggestions and perspectives.