# How to pass arbitrary arguments to wrapped groovy function?

Tags: groovy, wrapper, keyword-argument

I have a groovy wrapper function, and I want to pass any arbitrary arguments along to the wrapped method call.

Example:

```
// Arguments: appliance, temperature, duration
def cook(Map args = [:]) {
    print(args.appliance)
    print(args.temperature)
    print(args.duration)
}

// Arguments: appliance, plus whatever arguments cook() has
def cookWithKitchenAid(Map cookArgs = [:]) {
    cook(appliance: "KitchenAid " + cookArgs.appliance, cookArgs)
}

cookWithKitchenAid(appliance: "oven", temperature: "300", duration: "60")
```

Python has a way of passing arbitrary keyword arguments along, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/36611057/1698736 .  What is the equivalent in groovy?

Comment: You mean like this? `cook( cookArgs + [  appliance: "KitchenAid " + cookArgs.appliance] )`

Comment: Yes.  Thank you.